# Why can't the id field be used in where caluse with EclipseLink

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I'm moving an application from Hibernate to EclipseLink.
I have the following named query:

```
delete from MyObject where id<=:LAST_ID
```

The query worked fine with Hibernate but fails with the following error with EclipseLink:

> The identification variable 'id' cannot be used in conjunction with the <= operator.

Isn't it allowed to use the ID field in the where caluse with JPA?

Any workaround will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax which worked for me was:

```
delete from MyObject mo where mo.id <= :LAST_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can always use `Delete From MyObject Where MyObject <= :LAST_ID` with the same effect. Anyway, if you post you Entity definition, we could be more helpful.